# Ionic 3 - Two ionic sliders are showing same current index

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

Two sliders on the same page working but when adding different functions for both on `ionSlideDidChange`, it shows the same current `index`.

Comment: Your answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885386/ionic3-multiple-swiper-sliders-on-samepage

Comment: Also here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44321593/how-can-manage-multiple-slider-in-ionic2-for-web-application

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ionic3 multiple swiper sliders on samepage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885386/ionic3-multiple-swiper-sliders-on-samepage)